# Create new class object

Tags: python

I have 2 class in python cl1 in f1.py file and cl2 in f2.py file. I wrote import f2

```
import f2

class cl1:
  a = f2.cl2()
```

But i see error in `a = f2.cl2()`: module object has no attribute 'cl2'

Why?

Thank you.

Comment: could you please post the contents of f2.py? I have to assume the error message means exactly that: You have not defined cl2 in f2...

Comment: @sterh: Please UPDATE the question to post the relevant code from f2.py.

Answer (score 1):

sorry, i was wrong:
your problem is probably that you have a circular import: f1 imports f2 and vice versa.
check your design, as it usually should be possible to design your software without a circular import.

see: [this](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19343)

Comment: I deleted import f1 in f2.py and now i have Import error in f1: cannot import name cl2

Comment: if f1.py still contains an "import f2" then your code should work fine.
f2.py doesn't have to know anything about the modules of f1.py

Answer (score 0):

The following code works just fine (if you're using Python 3 you can omit the `(object)` parts, but in Python 2 you should leave them in -- they're not responsible for your bug, but if you get used to omitting them you'll have strange problems in the future as your code grows...):

`f2.py` is:

```
class cl2(object):
  pass
```

`f1.py` is:

```
import f2

class cl1(object):
  a = f2.cl2()
```

If your code is not working, it must be different from this.  Please confirm that this simple code is working for you, then show us (by editing your original question, *not* by posting comments or "answers") how your non-working code differs (lack of imports, circular imports, wrong imports, or whatever else).